# What are execution context and reflection-only context in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

I am having a hard time understanding the concepts *execution context* and *reflection-only context* in .Net. From what I understand these are two different ways to load assemblies, but I can not define them clearly.

About execution context I was able to find [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.executioncontext?view=netframework-4.8) of the `ExecutionContext` class on msdn and about the reflection-only context, only [how to load assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-load-assemblies-into-the-reflection-only-context) into it.

Can somebody provide a description of these two concepts?

Comment: `An execution context is the managed equivalent of a COM apartment.` `The reflection-only load context allows you to examine assemblies compiled for other platforms or for other versions of the .NET Framework. Code loaded into this context can only be examined; it cannot be executed. This means that objects cannot be created, because constructors cannot be executed.` _Both are quotes from your links._ The former lets you run things. The latter lets you examine things.

Comment: You've already answered you question almost:) Reflection only context is only for examining code for reflection purposes, not for code execution

Comment: @mjwills so what is a context like this? Is it a per thread memory location? Is it some environment shared between processes? I appreciate that you are trying to provide me with some information, but the reason why I asked the question is because I don't understand what are those.

Comment: @mjwills I don't think it does, I am trying to find a definition for what are these contexts. I am not trying to solve anything, but to find my way through some msdn documentation.

Comment: `so what is a context like this? Is it a per thread memory location? Is it some environment shared between processes?` The short answer is - I don't believe it is documented in terms of that level of implementation detail. So while I could describe how **one particular implementation** acts, that isn't much help to you. So, for example - it isn't shared between processes _at the moment_ - but _maybe_ it might in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A .NET assembly contains many things. Generally, they contain types (classes et al) and metadata (information about what those types look like, and much more).

You access metadata using reflection.

If you're *only* interested in the metadata, and not in actually using the types from an assembly, you can load said assembly in a reflection-only context. This enables you to load and inspect assembly metadata, but not actually instantiate types from that assembly.

A good resource about all this is [CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454). For some short info, see [MSDN Blogs: Reflection Only Assembly Loading](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2004/08/24/reflection-only-assembly-loading/).

Also a good read is [this framework documentation: Assemblies in the Common Language Runtime -> Assembly Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/assembly-contents):

> In general, a static assembly can consist of four elements:
>
> - The assembly manifest, which contains assembly metadata.
> - Type metadata.
> - Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) code that implements the types.
> - A set of resources.

And [How to: Load Assemblies into the Reflection-Only Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-load-assemblies-into-the-reflection-only-context)
:

> The reflection-only load context allows you to examine assemblies compiled for other platforms or for other versions of the .NET Framework. Code loaded into this context can only be examined; it cannot be executed. This means that objects cannot be created, because constructors cannot be executed. Because the code cannot be executed, dependencies are not automatically loaded. If you need to examine them, you must load them yourself.

So the reflection-only context is not really a different process, or a different thread, or anything else, but just a way of loading assemblies without loading the code or dependencies therein. And the `Assembly` class instance representing the loaded assembly will be flagged as such using its [`Assembly.ReflectionOnly` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononly?view=netframework-4.8).

It just loads the **type metadata**, so you can inspect what the types in that assembly look like.

Comment: Okay, so these contexts are not actually some environments, but they are more like states of the objects loaded, is this right?

Comment: They tell the runtime that the code/assembly loaded can execute code or not (among other things). For example, if you want to just inspect the classes/attributes/properties/resources and not call into functions to execute code, you may load in "reflection only" context. It's also helpful if you don't fully trust the assembly you're inspecting. Although to my understanding, reflectionOnly is not a security feature.